# AngularJS: Count iterations of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-repeat to make a grid of consecutive numbers?

I can use two ng-repeats to make a grid like this:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in [1, 2, 3]">
    <td ng-repeat="r in [1, 2, 3]">
            {{c * r}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which outputs this:

```
1    2    3
2    4    6
3    6    9
```

But the output I want is:

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

Or is there a more appropriate angular directive I could use?

Comment: `{{$index+$parent.$index*rArr.length+1}}`

Comment: map the data in controller that is needed

Comment: It shouldn't be the responsibility of the view to generate data.

Comment: Yep, definitely. But, this isn't data, it's for static UI elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in [0, 1, 2]">
    <td ng-repeat="r in [1, 2, 3]">
            {{c * 3 + r}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or, if you don't want to change the first array:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="c in [1, 2, 3]">
    <td ng-repeat="r in [1, 2, 3]">
            {{(c-1) * 3 + r}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Enjoyed the answer! :)

Comment: this works only for this scenario.. will this work eg:  1,2,3,4 ??

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi: well, if the array is called `myArray` then it's possible to replace `3` with `myArray.length`

Comment: Yes correct.. .but why this much complex expressions.. cant we do simple logic ?